# How to modularize and combine my library?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, lodash

I'm new to modular JS but I like the concept. I want to write my small library to test things out. This is how I want it to look like:

- it has 5 methods
- You can download a full library which exports a global variable - Frog. It's a module which doesn't have anything on its own but it downloads its 5 standalone methods as dependencies
- You can access all methods of the Frog library like normal, for example Frog.get(), Frog.animate() etc.

I know how to write something like this but can I modularize it like this?

- You can download 4 out of 5 modules
- The first downloaded module called Frog.animate creates an empty Frog object and adds .animate method
- The second downloaded module called .css takes the previous Frog object with .animate and adds .css to that object
- and so on... basically adding methods to just one object

Is something like this possible? And how? I know Lodash is very modularized and you can cherrypick methods. Are they just single functions like forEach() instead of _.forEach() or is it something different?

How should I modularize all these Frog methods? Export them as standalone single functions like this?

```
var animate = require("./Frog.animate");
animate(something);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can import anything what you export.

frog.js

```
const a = () => ...;

function b() {
    ...
}

function c() {
    ...
}

class D {
    ...
}

module.exports = { a, b, c, D };
```

index.js

```
import { a, D } from './frog'
```

Using the above, you can also do it the other way around. Create subfeatures in different files and let your `frog` library import them and export all as a module.

Comment: You shouldn't mix CommonJS modules with ES modules IMHO, this may introduce errors (especially with the `export default` behavior).